# How to convert model to string for upstream messages?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello I am building an app  where I am using Firebase upstream messages. But when I click to send upstream msg I must put some object in that message. This is my function where I have that model:

```
 public void getObjectEvent(EventModel data){
    Map dataa = new HashMap();
    dataa.put("message","Upstream message.");
    Gson datajson = new Gson();
    datajson.toJson(data);
    FirebaseMessaging fm=FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
            .addData("action","message")
            .addData("data","{\"message\":\"Upstream Message\"}")
            .addData("object", data)
            .build());


}
```

In this part:

```
  .addData("object", data)
```

It gives me an error because this "data" has to be String  but for my needs I must send object(Event model)
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hold returned value of `toJson`:

```
String json = datajson.toJson(data);
```

And set the json string to `addData`:

```
.addData("object", json)
```

Finaly your method will be like this:

```
public void getObjectEvent(EventModel data){
    Map dataa = new HashMap();
    dataa.put("message","Upstream message.");
    Gson datajson = new Gson();
    String json = datajson.toJson(data);
    FirebaseMessaging fm=FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
            .addData("action","message")
            .addData("data","{\"message\":\"Upstream Message\"}")
            .addData("object", json)
            .build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  String jsonData = datajson.toJson(data);

   ///
  .addData("object", jsonData)
```

by this, you can send the model as JSONObject.